# Forms opens two times

Tags: c#

In the code below, I open a form with frmContact.ShowDialog(); and then when I close the form by clicking on the OK button in the form it closes, but then it opens again because I have the frmContact.ShowDialog() in the if statement. Could this be done in some oterh way?

```
        // Button add new customer
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();

        frmContact.ShowDialog(); // Show the contact form window

        if (frmContact.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get rid of the first `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Aha! That was simple! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

Simply remove the first call:

```
ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();

if (frmContact.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK", "Test", ...);
}
```

Another option (especially useful if the code that shows the form is not next to the code that checks the return value) is to use [`Form.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx):

```
ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();
frmContact.ShowDialog();

if (frmContact.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK", "Test", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the **second** if, like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();   

    if (frmContact.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //just one call
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();

    frmContact.ShowDialog();
}
```